# How to test with jasmine a script called in index.html

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a problem.

I have a script that is being loaded in the index.html file.

```
    function getSurvey(token, user) {
  createSoluCXWidget(
    token,
    "bottomBox",
    {
      "client_id": user.client_id,
      "store_id": user.store_id,
      "transaction_id": user.transaction_id,
    });
}
```

In my function, I call this guy with a (window as any) and it works, but when testing it, it gives an error for not finding the getSurvey() method, what am I doing wrong?

```
enableNpsAndCsat(): void {   
this.accessService
  .getAccess().then((access: Access) => (this.configSurvey(access)));
}

private configSurvey(access: Access): void {
        this.sub.sink = this.userService.getUser(access?.user)
        .subscribe(user => {
          this.userParams = this.setParamsSurvey(user);
          (window as any).getSurvey('tokenTeste', this.userParams)
        },
          () => {
            this.onShowError();
          });
      }
```

nps.spec.ts

```
 it('Access service getUser', fakeAsync(() => {
  const user = new ResponseAPI<User>({fakeUser});
  spyHttp = spyOn(userService, 'getUser').and.returnValue(of(user));
  
  component.enableNpsAndCsat();
  tick(600);
  expect(spyHttp).toHaveBeenCalled();
  flush();
}));
```

Comment: Your test case doesnt make any sense, it testing a function that you have not provided, please check!

Comment: what function? because the window function is called in the configSurvey > getSurvey. I'm calling **enableNpsAndCsat()** as configSurvey is private

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).